# Clone section of form & retain values on error (PHP & jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, pear

I'm editing a portion of a job application form where the applicant can add multiple "previous employer" values. There are several fields in this portion that I need to clone and retain the values for upon submission. The cloned fields should stay populated if there are submission errors.

The site already uses jQuery and is using PHP & Pear to handle the form submission and validation.

```
<h3>Previous Employer</h3>              
<ul>
    <li>                
      <span>Date of Hire</span>
        <input type="text" name="field41" value="<? echo $_POST['field41']; ?>" class="sm requiredField"> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>End Date </span>
        <input type="text" name="field42" value="<? echo $_POST['field42']; ?>" class="sml requiredField"> 
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
      <span>Name of Employer </span>
        <input type="text" name="field43" value="<? echo $_POST['field43']; ?>" class="sm requiredField"> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Address </span>
        <input type="text" name="field44" value="<? echo $_POST['field44']; ?>" class="sml requiredField"> 
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="last" id="emp">
    <li>
      <span><a href="#emptop" class="add_emp_field">Add Another Position</a></span>  
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

What's the best way to handle the cloning of that chunk of fields + how can I retain their values so that the fields aren't emptied when there's an error? Additionally, how can I retain the value from a `<select>`field upon submission with errors?

Comment: You need to align the frontend javascript logic with the backend PHP form processing logic. That's very specifically in detail and I don't have an easy suggestion at hand how you could do it, especially as you have only shown some HTML chunk. In jQuery you can duplicate a fragment of HTML and then process it, e.g. counting numbers up for form fields. But the backend also needs to know then after submit, how many Positions have been created on the frontend to validate and process the values.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's supposed to automatically update the backend as well with the cloned user i would suggest using a ajax call to interact with the backend. Then you could in each ul (item) of the list have a rel attribute storing the id of the employee. Then when cloning you throw that id with the ajax call so it can gather correct information for the cloning.

Once a clone is made in the backend you could make it throw the data back as response. Mayb a JSON array? Once you got the data you could just append the list with your cloned item with the values you got from the ajax response.